# Delete First Word Of Text File Terminal Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, text-files

Is there a way to access a text file `file.txt` from my desktop and remove the first word from each line?

*Note, they are numbers but they are separated by a space such as words would be.

For example, could I change:

```
123 456
789 123
456 789
```

to:

```
456
123
789
```

And perhaps this isn't possible, I'm not sure.  But I have about 6000 lines and I'd rather not manually have to remove them all.  Does anyone have a solution for a mac user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print $2}' > out.txt
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thank you very much!  I can't select it as the correct answer for 9 minutes, but i will!

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma Do you want to me to explain the logic?  Or is it pretty clear?

Comment: That would be very helpful for future commands that I may need.  I can sorta figure out what some if it means.  I'm assuming "print $2" does the 2nd word, and I understand file.txt and out.txt.  But "cat", "|", "awk", and the general formatting mean nothing to me.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma cat is a utility that just spits out your file to the screen, in your case file.txt.  The | is called 'pipe' which tells the shell to take the output of the first program on the left side of the | and use it as input for the program to the right side. Therefore cat takes the output and gives it to awk.  awk is a pattern and text manipulation tool standard to many Unix operating systems and variants.  You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK 
The > tells the shell to write the output to the file called out.txt.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma Sorry for the long-winded response.  Those tools I used will come to you with more experience in the shell as they are very powerful.  I'm no expert by any means but Google is your friend often when you need to do some data manipulation.  There is often a solution! :)

Comment: Not an issue.  Thanks again for your help!